# Interval regression with R

Tags: r, regression, intervals, linear-regression

I need to perform a multiple regression analysis of response data that is expressed as an interval (a lower bound and an upper bound), that I assume is log-normally distributed, on a number of explanatory variables.

I found that the package `intReg` could perform this but haven't had much success as I keep getting the message.

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

These are the logs of my response data:

```
> head(y)
       lb       ub
[1,] 6.756932 6.852243
[2,] 6.246107 6.400257
[3,] 6.063785 6.246107
[4,] 7.019297 7.093405
[5,] 6.756932 6.852243
[6,] 6.400257 6.533789
```

Here are the two variables that I believe to be the most significant as an example:

```
> head(inc_lev)
[1] low    high   high   low    high   middle
Levels: high low middle

> head(usage)
[1] 12.9  8.6  4.3 17.2 12.9 12.9
```

Then I try to run the regression but all I get is:

```
> intreg<-intReg(y~inc_lev+usage, data=data)
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Warning messages:
1: In Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", loc) :
  OS reports request to set locale to "" cannot be honored
```

etc...

So my question would be: 1) What is the problem here, 2) What am I doing wrong, and 3) Is there another way to perform an interval regression in R?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: if you run `Sys.setlocale(category="LC_COLLATE")`, what does it say? Also, do you get your result, despite the warnings?

Comment: When I run your command I get `[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_COLLATE") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "" cannot be honored`. Also I don't get any results at all.

Comment: Are you sure? Try `summary(intreg)`. The function did not stop, it merely issued a warning. As far as I understand, this warning is about some incompatibility between your system locale and R's. See what locale (regional settings?) is set in your system (Windows?), and whether "." is used as decimal there.

Comment: Ok you're right. I do get a result for the simpler regression on two variables but another error arose when I include all my explanatory variables. `summary(intreg) Error in class(coefValues) <- c("coef.intReg", class(coefValues)) : attempt to set an attribute on NULL`

Comment: I'm getting the same error message. Did you ever find out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with date processing and had so far ignored it, but found this (old) post and decided to determine a fix for it.

What you need to do is to set `LC_COLLATE` to some sensible value, either in the environment before starting R (`export LC_COLLATE=C`) or from within R:

```
> as.gset(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))
{<<POSIXct>>}
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", loc) :
  OS reports request to set locale to "" cannot be honored
> Sys.getenv("LC_COLLATE")
[1] ""
> Sys.setenv("LC_COLLATE"="C")
> as.gset(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))
{<<POSIXct>>}
> Sys.unsetenv("LC_COLLATE")
> as.gset(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))
{<<POSIXct>>}
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", loc) :
  OS reports request to set locale to "" cannot be honored
```

Note that there's no error message after `Sys.setenv(LC_COLLATE="C")` for the gset operation with dates. I know you were not using sets or dates, but I think warnings in both cases may have been caused by the same underlying reason (collation and locale).

If anyone has had a similar warning and could test whether `Sys.setlocale` helps in the case, please write a comment on how it worked.

Comment: your fix works! I tried intReg on my own data first, got the problem that user224081 got. So I tried running the example of the intReg package and I also got the warning messages! I wish they mentioned this problem in the package reference. Thank you!